# how to get value from array with stdclass object?

Tags: php

I have get following output in codeigniter?

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 8
            [book_category] => C Program
            [book_id] => 2
            [book_name] => C Language
            [book_category_id] => 8
            [book_in_stock] => 5
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 8
            [book_category] => C Program
            [book_id] => 1
            [book_name] => C++
            [book_category_id] => 8
            [book_in_stock] => 10
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 9
            [book_category] => English
            [book_id] => 3
            [book_name] => Comp Eng
            [book_category_id] => 9
            [book_in_stock] => 5
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 9
            [book_category] => English
            [book_id] => 4
            [book_name] => Eng English
            [book_category_id] => 9
            [book_in_stock] => 5
        )

)
```

so i need get value from the above array without foreach of debugging purpose?

Comment: Have provided with a solution for the request that you have asked the question. Have a try and share thoughts.

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
echo $array[0]->id;
echo $array[0]->book_category;
```

Comment: how do you get the output above (the one in your question)?

Answer (score 4):

This will get the value easily out

```
foreach($array as $key =>$value){ 
  echo $array[$key]->id;
  echo $array[$key]->book_category;
}
```

Comment: Sorry i didn't see the "without" have you tried for ($x=0;$x<count($array);$x++){ echo $array[$x]->id;}

Answer (score 1):

[var_dump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) is the way to go if you wan to see the content of your array easily.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are never get echoed,Try this with print_r();